# Replace inbuilt Calender with GNOME Calender on Top Bar

Tags: gnome-shell, calendar, gnome-calendar

I tried to see if I could add events to my in-build top-bar calender.

I was prompted to install GNOME Calender, is there a way to replace the native top-bar Ubuntu calender with the new GNOME calender?

Comment: You're right! They do show up in the top bar!

I guess my question would now be is there a button I can add to allow me to create an event through the top bar calender, and not through GNOME calender.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to replace anything with another thing. The top-bar calender in GNOME Shell is in sync with the pre-installed GNOME Calendar. If you and an event to GNOME Calender, it would also appear in the top-bar calender.

Right now there seems to be no other way to add events to the top-bar calender, so you have to add events to the GNOME Calendar application.

Comment: If you install Evolution (as I do), GNOME top bar calendar (and GNOME calendar application as well) becomes synced with calendar(s) configured in Evolution.

Comment: @raj Yes, it's actually because of `evolution-data-server` which provides a unified backend for applications dealing with calendar information (and also contact, task etc.). Note that `evolution-data-server` is pre-installed as an essential package even if you don't install the `evolution` frontend.